EKS kube-state-metrics errors after upgrading the cluster
I upgraded EKS cluster from 1.21 to 1.29, goes through upgrading both of cluster and compute nodes steps, re applied my helm files, modified HPA for some services to use the new format, everything goes well so far, but i am getting errors from kube-state-metrics (its sent to data dog),
with the following:
  kube-state-metrics 
 v1beta1.certificationRequest the server could not find the requested resource
 v1beta1.cronjob              the server could not find the requested resource
 v1beta1.ingress              the server could not find the requested resource


      

I cannot figure out whats produce those errors, as all my resources working as expected and accessible!, any idea how to get rid of it? thanks.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

It might be because of kube-state-metrics compatibility with EKS cluster. Check and update the kube-state-metrics as given here.

Thank you, its worked, the deployment was old using old image version of kube-state-metrics, after updating the yaml and re apply its worked.
